# MS Word: Change font-size in table autoformat

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

After trying it for a few times, I can't seem to edit the font size through  Ms Word's Table -> Table Autoformat. I can edit a lot of other stuff except for the font size. Are there any explanations or workaround  to this?

thanks

Comment: Select your whole table and change the fonts using the font toolbar above.

Comment: Counter productive since I have 300 tables

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of guesswork about what you want and what you have, maybe the following would suit:

Table Tools, Design, Table Styles, Modify Table Style, select font to suit.